# JOptionPane displaying some HTML tags literally

Tags: java, html, swing, joptionpane

I'm getting some inconsistent HTML display in a Swing message dialog. The first example call below is fine, but the second one displays one of the break tags as literal text. What's going on here?

```
import javax.swing.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "<html>line 1<br>line 2<br>line 3");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                "<html>line 1<br>\nline 2<br>\nline 3");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't <br> and \n the exact same thing? If so I would get rid of the \n. That is the only difference I can see between the two.

Comment: Why use `<br>` at all?  A `<p>` can better handles paragraphs, an `<li>` can better represent lists, and a style applied to the `<body>` can best limit the width.  And what is the *point* of `\n`?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I don't have control over the real HTML; it comes to me like this. I could do search & replace on it but I wanted to understand why it was doing this.

Comment: I expect the reason it is doing it is because the HTML rendering engine of Swing was never intended for real world HTML, and it is stuffing up.  But try convincing Oracle to change it with a bug report (which I don't believe will be successful)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know what the problem is but it looks like a JLabel renders the HTML correctly:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>line 1<br>\nline 2<br>\nline 3");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);
```

Which doesn't really make sense because I thought a JOptionPane would us a JLabel to render the text?

Comment: I did some experimenting. A plain JLabel does not do line breaks, so JOptionPane splits multiline strings into multiple JLabels. This is why the subsequent tags display literally, because only the first JLabel gets the part of the message containing the `<html>` tag. It also causes formatting to not persist across lines. Thanks though; your workaround works great!

Comment: @Boann, Yes, I was just going to add that the `BasicOptionPaneUI` class does a search for the newline string (\n, \r\n) in the `addMessageComponents(...)` method  and then does the extra processing in the `burstString(...)` method (in case you want to look at the code).

Answer (score 0):

So do something like this

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
"<html>line 1<br>line 2<br>line 3");
```

Comment: While this question is not very clear, it seems to me that quoting the OP's first string back to them is 'not an answer'.

Comment: Yeah I didn't catch that, my mistake.